# Vue.JS: On click CLICK-ME, I want change background-color only this CHANGE-COLOR

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

```
<div v-for="(todo, n) in todos"> 
   <i class="CLICK-ME"></i>
   <li class="CHANGE-COLOR">
     {{ todo.name }} 
   </li>
</div>
```

`like`
 $(document).on('click', '.CLICK-ME', function(){ $(this).css("background-color", "red"); });

`or`
 $(document).on('click', '.CLICK-ME', function(){  $(this).addClass('red'); });

Answer (score 0):

You should change the color as follows:

```
<div v-for="(todo, n) in todos"> 
   <i class="CLICK-ME" @click="$event.target.classList.toggle('red')"></i>
   <li class="CHANGE-COLOR">
     {{ todo.name }} 
   </li>
</div>
```